# What does "you guessed an inch off" mean?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning, definition

I don't know how to explain the context. Two people are speaking about the Budapest oil deal of 1931.

> Kurt to Teck: "You too wish to go back to Europe?"
>
> Teck: "Yes."
>
> Kurt: "But they do not much want you. Not since the Budapest oil deal
>   of '31."
>
> Teck: "You seem as well informed about me as I am about you."
>
> Kurt: "That must have been a conference of high comedy, that one.
>   Everybody trying to guess whether Kessler was working for Fritz
>   Thyssen, and what Thyssen really wanted--and whether this 'National
>   Socialism' was a smart blind of Thyssen's, and where was Wolff. I
>   should like to have seen you and your friends. It is too bad: **you
>   guessed an inch off**, eh?
>
> Teck: "**More than an inch**."
>
> Kurt: "And Kessler has a memory? I do not think Herr Blecher would pay
>   you money for a description of a man who has a month to travel. But I
>   think he would pay you in a visa.

I think it means "- You began to guessing a little? - Not a little" I couldn't find any dictionary entries about "guess off" or "guess an inch off" though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Guess an inch off" is not an established phrase.

The sense of "off" here is "missing the target", so "guessing an inch off" means "Making a guess that is a little way away from the correct answer".

Comment: So, Teck's answering "Not a little, my guess is really bad."?

Comment: Yes, that's right.